# Make a method only accesable to certain objects in a template class

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list

I have a very confusing problem with java *generics*. I've never before experimented with those *generics* classes, but I decided to give it a go.
I've created my own LinkedList class that can make List structure of any objects.

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

private Node first, last;
private int size;

private class Node {
    T data;
    Node next;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}
...
public int seek(String name) {
    int i = -1;
    int counter = 0;
    Node t = first;
    while(t != null) {
        if(t.data.toString().equals(name)) {
            i = counter;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
        t = t.next;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I want the ***seek*** method only be accessible from objects that inherit from one of my other classes ( which have names ), since I plan for LinkedList to be usable by any objects, but that method only by certain ones. How can I achieve this? (To clarify my question I want to STOP objects from getting this method, I'm aware I can use `instanceof` )

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: I've made a mistake, pressed enter. Derp... It's fixed

Comment: Note: in Java, 'templates' are called generics. This isn't C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using complicated, hackish reflection tricks, can you get these two classes in a package without any others (unless the others are classes you don't mind being able to access this method)? If so, make `seek()` package-protected (no access modifier). Then, in your other class, add a declaration like this:

```
protected static int seek(LinkedList<?> list, String name) {
    return list.seek(name);
}
```

The `protected` modifier ensures access is limited to subclasses of your class. They can't actually call it on an instance of your `LinkedList` class in the usual syntax, but this works too.

Comment: So LinkedList(s) with classes that I want to use seek on need to go in the same package, and other classes(outside the package) can use the List methods without that method..?

Comment: @destroyergm Sorry for the late reply, but you are correct. Like I said, the package stuff is a bit hackish, but the alternative is weird reflection that should never be used... the access modifiers do behave in the way you describe though.